# Fixing navbar sub-menus from going off-screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using the following script as navbar, however I can't figure out how to make the menus/submenus respect the screen sides, and not continue to open outside of the screen border..  I don't want to change the default behavior (direction) of all the menus, just to change it it it would be cut by any of the sides..

I found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985334/jquery-solution-for-keeping-dropdown-submenu-inside-screen) (and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512032/detect-if-dropdown-navigation-would-go-off-screen-and-reposition-it) too), but I don't know how to implement the same answer to this current code.

Example of the menu being cut by the side of the monitor:
[image]

Here is the code snippet, along with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/my45qsf6/) link too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* MAIN MENU */
  $('#main-menu > li:has(ul.sub-menu)').addClass('parent');
  $('ul.sub-menu > li:has(ul.sub-menu) > a').addClass('parent');

  $('#menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('#main-menu').slideToggle(300);
    return false;
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 700) {
      $('#main-menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url(../images/patterns/light_toast.png);
  color: #666;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  color: #23dbdb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 940px;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}


/* HEADER */

#wrap>header {
  background-color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
  float: right;
}


/* HEADER > MENU */

#main-menu {
  float: right;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#main-menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

#main-menu>li.parent {
  background-image: url(../images/plus-gray.png);
  background-size: 7px 7px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

#main-menu>li.parent>a {
  padding-left: 14px;
}

#main-menu>li>a {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main-menu>li:hover>a,
#main-menu>li.current-menu-item>a {
  color: #23dbdb;
}


/* HEADER > MENU > DROPDOWN */

#main-menu li {
  position: relative;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  /* level 2 */
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  top: 38px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {
  /* level 3+ */
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding-top: 0;
  left: 149px;
  top: 0px;
}

ul.sub-menu>li>a {
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-top: none;
  color: #bbb;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

ul.sub-menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.sub-menu>li:first-child {
  border-top: 3px solid #23dbdb;
}

ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu>li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
}

ul.sub-menu>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}

ul.sub-menu>li>a.parent {
  background-image: url(../images/arrow.png);
  background-size: 5px 9px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 95% center;
}

#main-menu li:hover>ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  /* show the submenu */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <div class="inner relative">
      <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/851659509f07dd2fe27882da61f0da0a?s=64" alt="fresh design web"></a>
      <a id="menu-toggle" class="button dark" href="#"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></a>
      <nav id="navigation">
        <ul id="main-menu">
          <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="http://www.freshdesignweb.com">Home</a></li>
          <li class="parent">
            <a href="#">Features</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-wrench"></i> Elements</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-credit-card"></i>  Pricing Tables</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-gift"></i> Icons</a></li>
              <li>
                <a class="parent" href="#"><i class="icon-file-alt"></i> Pages</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Full Width</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Double Sidebar</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li class="parent">
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Large Image</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Medium Image</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Masonry</a></li>
              <li>
                <a class="parent" href="#"><i class="icon-file-alt"></i> Pages ></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Full Width</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Double Sidebar</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Double Sidebar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Single Post</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your sub-sub menus you're aligning based on left margin at 149px, just use the same attribute but instead for the right. `right:149px;` instead of `left:149px;`

```
ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {
  /* level 3+ */
  right: 149px;
}
```

Also you can align the sub menus to the left of the nav items. To do this use :

```
ul.sub-menu { 
  /* level 2 */
  right: 0;
  left: initial;
}
```

I included both examples in this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* MAIN MENU */
  $('#main-menu > li:has(ul.sub-menu)').addClass('parent');
  $('ul.sub-menu > li:has(ul.sub-menu) > a').addClass('parent');

  $('#menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('#main-menu').slideToggle(300);
    return false;
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 700) {
      $('#main-menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url(../images/patterns/light_toast.png);
  color: #666;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  color: #23dbdb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 940px;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}


/* HEADER */

#wrap>header {
  background-color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
  float: right;
}


/* HEADER > MENU */

#main-menu {
  float: right;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#main-menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 2px 0;
}

#main-menu>li.parent {
  background-image: url(../images/plus-gray.png);
  background-size: 7px 7px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}

#main-menu>li.parent>a {
  padding-left: 14px;
}

#main-menu>li>a {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main-menu>li:hover>a,
#main-menu>li.current-menu-item>a {
  color: #23dbdb;
}


/* HEADER > MENU > DROPDOWN */

#main-menu li {
  position: relative;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  /* level 2 */
  display: none;
  top: 38px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 9999;
  right:0;
  left:initial;
}

ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {
  /* level 3+ */
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding-top: 0;
  right: 149px;
  top: 0px;
}

ul.sub-menu>li>a {
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-top: none;
  color: #bbb;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

ul.sub-menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.sub-menu>li:first-child {
  border-top: 3px solid #23dbdb;
}

ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu>li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
}

ul.sub-menu>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}

ul.sub-menu>li>a.parent {
  background-image: url(../images/arrow.png);
  background-size: 5px 9px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 95% center;
}

#main-menu li:hover>ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  /* show the submenu */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <div class="inner relative">
      <a class="logo" href="#"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/851659509f07dd2fe27882da61f0da0a?s=64" alt="fresh design web"></a>
      <a id="menu-toggle" class="button dark" href="#"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></a>
      <nav id="navigation">
        <ul id="main-menu">
          <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="http://www.freshdesignweb.com">Home</a></li>
          <li class="parent">
            <a href="#">Features</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-wrench"></i> Elements</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-credit-card"></i>  Pricing Tables</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-gift"></i> Icons</a></li>
              <li>
                <a class="parent" href="#"><i class="icon-file-alt"></i> Pages</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Full Width</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Double Sidebar</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li class="parent">
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Large Image</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Medium Image</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Masonry</a></li>
              <li>
                <a class="parent" href="#"><i class="icon-file-alt"></i> Pages ></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Full Width</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Double Sidebar</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Double Sidebar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Single Post</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I just want it to behave that way only if it would be cut be the monitor,,  not the default behavior.

Comment: This is what you're looking for then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512032/detect-if-dropdown-navigation-would-go-off-screen-and-reposition-it Check if the screen offset to the left of the element + the width of the element is > the screen width. Then apply stylings using jquery .css().

Comment: Yes, I already put this link in the question above, I am just not sure how to apply it with the current script.  Can you please edit your answer to reflect that so I can test it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the real question here is, where do you want it to go? If there's no page real estate to the right of your menu, you can't place the submenu to the right, you have to place it to the left.

```
ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu { /* level 3+ */
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding-top: 0;
    left: -149px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Note, the left value is changed from 149px to -149px. That places the submenu to the left (where you have screen real estate), and not to the right, where you don't.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change the default behavior..  I want it to do that only if it would be cut from the sides..  Or else the first menu would be cut the same way too.

Comment: So what do you want to happen to give you the screen real estate to display the submenu? Do you want to move its parent menu to the left, to make room for it, even though it won't line up under its menu header?

Comment: The same ok to the other side, but only if it would be cut..  if it is not going to be cut, then it behaves as the main css.

Comment: Something like this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512032/detect-if-dropdown-navigation-would-go-off-screen-and-reposition-it